# How to use nesting in Tailwind using tailwind/nesting?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

The [documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#nesting) of TailwindCSS says that to use nesting in Tailwind one just needs to include the 'tailwindcss/nesting' plugin in the postcss.config.js file. This is what that file looks for me.

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: {
        'postcss-import': {},
        'tailwindcss/nesting': {},
        tailwindcss: {},
        autoprefixer: {},
    }
  }
```

I have a script running that takes an `input.css` file as input and outputs it to a `style.css` with all the Tailwind utility classes. Below is the `input.css` file. I can see the same CSS code I wrote for the `main` and `p` tags in the `style.css` without any differences, meaning that the nested code is not being converted to conventional CSS by the plugin.

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

main {
    color: red;

    & p {
        color: blue;
    }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you see `postcss-netsing` in your packages?

Comment: @Amini I do see `postcss-nested` in the list but not `postcss-nesting`

Comment: You should install `postcss` and `postcss-nesting`.